# Dynamically caption in Angular grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In Angular, 
I want to dynamically adjust the titles in the grid.
I have the elements in the model as an array.
How can I print them in caption?

For example, let's say, we are in the week of 202010, so I want to dynamically write the next five weeks in the caption.
I have these weeks in the model as an array, but how can I print it on caption.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide proper description.

Comment: Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. Also consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As for now, we have no idea what your components and model are.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by printing your columns inside an ng-repeat.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <th ng-repeat="week in weekLists">{{week}}</th>
</th>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.weekLists = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
```